# make_scorer NotFittedError :Estimator not fitted, call `fit` before exploiting the model

Tags: scikit-learn, hyperparameters, gridsearchcv

I am trying to use a custom scoring function for my gridsearchCV .

```
def my_custom_loss_func(model,X_test,Y_test):
    train_view=pd.DataFrame(np.round(model.predict(X_test)),columns=['predicted'])
    train_view['original']=pd.DataFrame(Y_test).reset_index().delay
    train_view['difference']=train_view.original-train_view.predicted
    score = train_view[abs(train_view.difference) <=3 ].count()[2]/train_view.shape[0]*100
    return score
my_scorer = make_scorer(my_custom_loss_func, greater_is_better=True)
```

here my code for fitting the model

```
params = {"learning_rate"    : [0.05, 0.10, 0.15, 0.20, 0.25, 0.30 ] ,
 "max_depth"        : [ 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15],
 "min_child_weight" : [ 1, 3, 5, 7 ],
 "gamma"            : [ 0.0, 0.1, 0.2 , 0.3, 0.4 ],
 "colsample_bytree" : [ 0.3, 0.4, 0.5 , 0.7 ] }

folds = 3
param_comb = 5

skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=folds, shuffle = True, random_state = 1001)
model_lgbm = lgb.LGBMRegressor(n_estimators=300)

random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(model_lgbm, param_distributions=params, n_iter=param_comb, scoring=my_scorer(model_lgbm,X_train,y_train), n_jobs=4, cv=skf.split(X_train,y_train), verbose=3, random_state=1001 )
random_search.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

I am getting this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotFittedError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-101-8b3c5a6432af> in <module>
----> 1 random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(model_lgbm, param_distributions=params, n_iter=param_comb, scoring=my_scorer(model_lgbm,X_train,y_train), n_jobs=4, cv=skf.split(X_train,y_train), verbose=3, random_state=1001 )
      2 random_search.fit(X_train,y_train)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\scorer.py in __call__(self, estimator, X, y_true, sample_weight)
     89         """
     90 
---> 91         y_pred = estimator.predict(X)
     92         if sample_weight is not None:
     93             return self._sign * self._score_func(y_true, y_pred,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lightgbm\sklearn.py in predict(self, X, raw_score, num_iteration, pred_leaf, pred_contrib, **kwargs)
    648         """
    649         if self._n_features is None:
--> 650             raise LGBMNotFittedError("Estimator not fitted, call `fit` before exploiting the model.")
    651         if not isinstance(X, (DataFrame, DataTable)):
    652             X = _LGBMCheckArray(X, accept_sparse=True, force_all_finite=False)

NotFittedError: Estimator not fitted, call `fit` before exploiting the model.
```

I am not able to understand where I am going wrong

Answer (score 0):

Your custom loss function should have as argument only `y_pred` and `y_true`. 
The error you're getting arise because of the first line in your function `model.predict(X_test)`, because as the error state, you can use *model.predict* only with an already trained model.

Check this [Custom Loss Functions for Gradient Boosting](https://towardsdatascience.com/custom-loss-functions-for-gradient-boosting-f79c1b40466d)
 to see an example of how to write a custom loss function in sklearn.

Answer (score 0):

Using `model.**_Booster**.predict(X_input)` instead of `model.predict(X_input)` solved the issue for me.